# Proving $A\subset X$ is closed in a metric space with $f:X\rightarrow A$ continuous and $f|_{A} = id_A$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Given a metric space $X$, a subset $A \subset X$ and a continuous function $f:X\rightarrow A$ such that $f|_{A} = id_A$, prove that $A\subset X$ is closed.

A possible hint may be derived from part 1 of the same question which asked to prove that $X$ is Hausdorff iff $\Delta := \{ (x,x) | x\in X \}$ is closed in $X \times X$.

I was able to prove part 1, but despite part 2 seeming simple, I am at a loss... I tried the following strategies (those worth mentioning, at least):

1. (more of an intuition) Every metric space is $(T_4)$ therefore also Hausdorff. Then, using the fact that in the product topology, $\overline {A\times A} = \bar{A}\times \bar{A} $ trying (unsuccessfully) to connect this to $\Delta$ to obtain $A\times A = \bar{A}\times \bar{A}$. No concrete developments beyond this intuition.
2. Starting from the fact that $A$ is closed in $(A, d|_{A \times A } )$, and therefore $f^{-1}(A)$ is closed in $X$. Then trying to prove, using separation axioms, that $A=f^{-1}(A)$, but this too didn't yield any results.

What am I missing? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $(x_n)\subset A$ with $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=x\in X$. Then $$A\ni f(x)=f\left(\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n\right)=\lim_{n\to \infty}f(x_n)=\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=x,$$ hence $A$ is closed.